# best practice and utility in python exceptions

Tags: python, error-handling, except

Firstly, I have found this piece of code

```
try:
    iter(iterable)
 except Exception as error:
    raise error
```

I am currently startingt to learn python but, that code is the same as if it wasn't anything right? Is the default behaviour of python right? Or it have some utility?
I should like to ask also, if in our programs is better practice to stop the program execution when handling errors or to handle them and continue the execution.
I guess that it depends on the program, but in a general way how should it be?

By default what I think is that the program should stop, but in this case why to handle the exception ?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense. "The same as if it wasnt anything" The same is if what was not anything? As for your question about good practice with error handling: it depends. It is generally good practice not to catch an error unless you are expecting it specifically for some reason, otherwise, your code should not really be throwing errors in the first place.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the program behaviour would not change if that try, except was not in the code, sorry for my expression. And thank you so much!

Comment: No, this code doesn't really do anything useful. You would get the same effect (though faster) by  not catching the exception raised by `iter` in the first place.

Comment: It might make sense to catch the exception, *log it*, then re-raise it.

Comment: A try except usefull when you can't avoid the possibility of hitting an error and you have a way of handling it without the need to exit the program.

Comment: The traceback of the exception would look differently and contain slightly different data. But this seems of no use.